# Postgres duplicate error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I am getting this error when I try to recreate a model in postgres

`PG::DuplicateTable: ERROR:  relation "images" already exists`

I am recreating this database and have deleted the migration, rolledback the database and (for what I know) deleted all traces of the previous table.

However, when I try to do a `dropdb` command, I get the following error.

`dropdb: database removal failed: ERROR:  database "images" does not exist`

Thank you for you help.

Comment: Have you tried `rake db:reset`?

Comment: You're mixing apples and pears here - the error `dropdb: database removal failed: ERROR:  database "images" does not exist` is telling you the database `images` does not exist. However the table may exist

Answer (score 0):

This is because you do not have a rollback method in your migration, try the following: `$ rails db:drop db:create db:migrate`